# Magmi: Attributes not being associated with attribute sets

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, import, magmi, attribute-set

I've successfully added attributes and attribute sets to the store I'm working on, however I'm running into trouble with creating associations between the attributes and attribute sets.

When I check an attribute set in the Magento backend, the Groups column is completely empty, and all the attributes appear to be available in the Unassigned Attributes column.

This is a sample from my csv for creating associations:

```
attribute_set_name  attribute_code  attribute_group_name
AC Gearmotor        FullLoadAmps    General
AC Gearmotor        MountingStyle   General
AC Gearmotor        RPM             General
AC Gearmotor        Torque          General
```

These are my settings in Magmi for the Attribute association import options:

```
attribute_set_name,attribute_code,attribute_group_name
*,name,General
*,description,General
*,short_description,General
*,sku,General
*,weight,General
*,news_from_date,General
*,news_to_date,General
*,status,General
*,url_key,General
*,visibility,General
*,manufacturer,General
*,country_of_manufacture,General
*,allowed_to_quotemode,General
*,group_allow_quotemode,General
*,quotemode_conditions,General
*,price,Prices
*,group_price,Prices
*,special_price,Prices
*,special_from_date,Prices
*,special_to_date,Prices
*,tier_price,Prices
*,msrp_enabled,Prices
*,msrp_display_actual_price_type,Prices
*,msrp,Prices
*,tax_class_id,Prices
*,price_view,Prices
*,meta_title,Meta Information
*,meta_keyword,Meta Information
*,meta_description,Meta Information
*,image,Images
*,small_image,Images
*,thumbnail,Images
*,media_gallery,Images
*,gallery,Images
*,is_recurring,Recurring Profile
*,recurring_profile,Recurring Profile
*,custom_design,Design
*,custom_design_from,Design
*,custom_design_to,Design
*,custom_layout_update,Design
*,page_layout,Design
*,options_container,Design
*,gift_message_available,Gift Options
```

Create attribute associations from CSV which are not in database

Update attribute associations from CSV which are already in database

Which generates the following/similar error for each association which I attempt:

```
Attribute Set Importer v0.0.2 - Exception in update/insert loop for entity 
'attribute association' in record no 1: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 
1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`brennerf_6b6AnYRQ`.
`i2r7_eav_entity_attribute`, CONSTRAINT `FK_917A5725E0970D5A68B169EEBCDED200` 
FOREIGN KEY (`attribute_group_id`) REFERENCES `i2r7_eav_attribute_group` 
(`attribute_group_id`)

record data:Array
(
  [attribute_group_name] => General
  [entity_type_id] => 4
  [attribute_set_id] => 23683
  [attribute_id] => 515
)

original record data:Array
(
  [attribute_set_name] => AC Gearmotor
  [attribute_code] => FullLoadAmps
  [attribute_group_name] => General
  [entity_type_id] => 4
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Appears I had missed a step, and did not add the magmi:groups column to the attribute set import csv.

Comment: Ca you elaborate on what you mean?